# Assigned value in inner class not assigned correctly

Tags: java, android, anonymous-inner-class

I have this function to return number of nodes at a firestore endpoint but it seems not to ork as expected. Currently, the number of nodes at the endpoint is 1.Here is the function

```
public static int getInvoicesCount(String uid)
{
    final int[] count = new int[1];

    FirebaseFirestore firestore;
    firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    CollectionReference invoicesRef = firestore
            .collection("invoices");

    Query query = invoicesRef.whereEqualTo("creator_id",uid);

    Task<QuerySnapshot> task = query.get();


    task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                if(task.getResult().isEmpty())
                {
                    count[0] = 0;
                    Log.d("counter",String.valueOf(count[0]));
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("counter is",String.valueOf(task.getResult().size()));
                    count[0] = task.getResult().size();
                }

            }
        }
    });

    return count[0];

}
```

Logging the value of count[0] in the else statement gives 1 but the return value at the end of the function is still giving 0 instead of 1;

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do but this is the wrong way. Task is asynchron and getInvoicesCount is synchron ...

Comment: I don't know Android programming but `onComplete` seems to be called asynchronously, in another thread too, so after `query.get()` the return statement will be called. `onComplete` will be called later

Comment: So what is the suggestion? How do I solve it.

Comment: Which class is calling getInvoicesCount ? Maybe you can pass a reference to that class and call a method to update that class

Answer (score 0):

The code you have in `onComplete` method is invoked a lot after your method is returning, when your task is completed. In your code you are just attaching the listener, it can be called a lot later or even never at all.

You have a lot of options, for example [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Future.html), or attaching a callback to your listener (so listener calls the callback after it completes).

```java
task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful())
        {
            if(task.getResult().isEmpty())
            {
                count[0] = 0;
                Log.d("counter",String.valueOf(count[0]));
            }
            else {
                Log.d("counter is",String.valueOf(task.getResult().size()));
                count[0] = task.getResult().size();
            }

            methodWhenListenerCompletes(count[0]);
        }
    }
});
...
public void methodWhenListenerCompletes(int count) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: It is called in activity onCreate method which is similar to the main function

Comment: Don't understand both comments - you can see in my answer that I call the `methodWhenListenerCompletes(count[0])` at the end of the `onComplete` - typical callback. This is the similar idea to android's async task postExecute - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)

Comment: I was talking to ngenge